# Why Does the NetBSD System Call Manual Mention the Standard C Library?

Tags: man, netbsd

I'm reviewing man(2) pages on NetBSD 9, and have seen that all of the documents (write(2), open(2), pipe(2)) mention the Standard C Library at the top.

My understanding was that system calls were independent of library functions (such as those in libc). I don't see a similar mention in the Linux System call Manual. Does this mean that invoking these methods is calling some wrapper function included in libc, instead of directly calling a kernel function? Is this generally true, or just a feature of NetBSD?

Comment: You can only do system calls from assembly, not from C, so yes, any of those "system calls" from section 2 of the manual is actually a wrapper implemented in the standard C library (libc), which is linked either statically or dynamically into your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open()`, for example, is a C standard library function.

The *implementation* is dependent on the OS.  On Unix-like systems it's typically implemented as a syscall.

So the application calls `open()`, and that calls `syscall()` on Unix-like systems.

C has been ported to a lot of platforms, and not all of them have syscall functionality.  Their implementation is different.

So we say that things like `open()` are part of the standard C library, because the library abstracts from the underlying OS implementation.

Comment: They aren't part of the library defined by the C standard(s) ('highlevel' calls like fopen fwrite fputc are, 'lowlevel' calls like open write pipe aren't), but most C implementations especially on Unix for convenience bundle them in the same library _file_ canonically libc.whatever (OTOH some math routines, even though in standard C, are traditionally in a _separate_ file -lmath)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 "Standard C Library" here means libc, the library linked by `-lc`. I.e. it means the library implementing the majority of C language functionality (and POSIX extensions to that language). It has less to do with actual standards. See e.g. the [`pipe(2)` manual](https://man.netbsd.org/pipe.2).

Comment: `open(2)` does not call the `syscall(2)` wrapper. (On x86-64, system calls happen through a processor instruction called just `syscall`, but that's a different thing). Also, on Linux, `open(2)` is implemented as a wrapper for `openat(2)` -- the `open` system call is only kept for binary compatibility, and only on older platforms.